# How can i solve 500 internal server error

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I solve 500 internal server error ?

[image]

error.log :

```
[12-Jul-2016 11:20:25 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4104 bytes) in /home/giritra/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[12-Jul-2016 11:25:05 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) in /home/giritra/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[12-Jul-2016 11:29:22 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) in /home/giritra/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[12-Jul-2016 12:04:38 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65552 bytes) in /home/giritra/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php on line 1615
[15-Jul-2016 12:24:04 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of CustomImportExport_Export::export() should be compatible with Mage_ImportExport_Model_Export::export() in /home/giritra/public_html/export_product.php on line 1047
```

Comment: Also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126803/how-can-i-solve-the-error-allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-ex?rq=1

Comment: Also: **Please stop it**

Comment: @fschmengler : i get more information here.

Comment: You get the same information again and again. And I told you before, you should update your original question to add more details, not spread them over 10 different questions. An updated question is shown on the home page again, so it will be as visible as a new question (now don't get the idea that you could abuse that!)

Answer (score 2):

Please make change in your root .htaccess file

replace this:

```
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
```

With:

```
## enable rewrites

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
```

That may solve your problem!!

Comment: no improvement, same error.

Comment: Actually my problem is, i can able to export my products, but bulk export product only not working, which means 100's of products export successfully, but when i try to export my all product i get stuck ( bulk product export not worked)  in my store 20,000 products are there.

Comment: @ User34444 : i have tried both export options, help me to get out this problem,

Comment: system - import/export - export error:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/C5y2X.png

system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products error:

http://i.imgur.com/PkRsHxQ.png

Comment: Please increase the execution time of server and check using phpinfo function and confirm that your changes will apply. after that check the issue

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xWvo54t.png

Comment: still not working

Comment: Am confused totally, my export working, but bulk export only not working

Comment: is there any core file missing or any thing

Comment: in your question error log show the server memory issue, So please explain your question bit more

Comment: Chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42960/http-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-127180-how-can-i-solve-500-internal-se

Comment: Please increase `post_max_size` on server

Answer (score 1):

The php memory resource can be increased in the php.ini located in the public_html. The following steps will explain how to set the php.ini to allow a larger amount of memory use.

-> Open your cpanel
-> Select the Web root (public_html/www) directory and click Go.
-> Open the php.ini with the code editor.

-> Find the following section in the php.ini file.

```
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
```

Try increase the memory_limit value to 256M.

If the php memory_limit is already at 256M, you can increase it to 512M.
Save the changes.

Comment: THIS IS MY VALUE

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/xWvo54t.png

Comment: STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: any other options??

Comment: Actually my problem is, i can able to export my products, but bulk export product only not working, which means 100's of products export successfully, but when i try to export my all product i get stuck ( bulk product export not worked) in my store 20,000 products are there.

Comment: @  Dhrumin : i have tried both export options, help me to get out this problem,

Comment: system - import/export - export error:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/C5y2X.png

system - import/export - dataflow profiles - export all products error:

http://i.imgur.com/PkRsHxQ.png